# Unable to lock (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

First of all, I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so please be gentle.
I recently tried to dual boot Windows 7 with the most recent Ubuntu OS (14.04 i believe) and somehow managed to delete my entire windows partition. I decided I would bite the bullet, so to speak, and use Ubuntu exclusively until I can recover my windows and dual boot again.  I have really no other option seeing as final exams are coming up and whatnot.

Anyways, I finished my Ubuntu installation and reboot my computer.  After I hit enter to launch Ubuntu at the initial screen, my display goes purple and stays that way.  Sometimes a black screen comes up that says something about grub.
I decided to once again boot the live version from my USB and reinstall, choosing the option to replace my windows hard drive entirely.  Again upon rebooting, I could not advance into the operating system past that first screen.

I've done some googling and I decided that the boot-repair tool was my best bet.  I went ahead and tried to install through terminal but again, no such luck.
I used the lines, if that's of any help.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Following the `sudo-apt-get update` command I received the following messages:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily 
unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Again, I believe boot-repair is my key to recovery here, however I am confident that I could be way off track. 
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process